# show a week report starting monday

Tags: php, mysql

I want to generate a report based on this week and this month. How do I calculate this?

I mean: how do I get today's date and query the database based on the "... BETWEEN monday AND today"

Comment: what does `date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime("last monday"));` give you?

Comment: 2013-03-18 00:00:00 :) tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

date("N") will give you the day of the week ( 1-monday to 7-sunday )
So move back that number of days will take you back to Sunday.
BUT since we want Monday, N-1 will take you back to Monday instead

Monday 1 -(1-1) = 0 days
Tuesday 2 -(2-1) = 1 day
...
Sunday 7 - (7-1) = 6 days

date("Y-m-d", timestamp); will give the date
date("Y-m-d 00:00:00, timestamp) will give the datetime

date("Y-m-01", timestamp); will give the first day of the month

Use these in you query as required

e.g.

```
<?php
$month_start=date("Y-m-01");
$last_monday=date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-".(date("N")-1)." days"));
$today=date("Y-m-d");
$sql1="SELECT * FROM table WHERE my_date BETWEEN :month_start AND :today";
$sql2="SELECT * FROM table WHERE my_date BETWEEN :last_monday AND :today";

?>
```

I've omitted the sql as we dont know if your mysql_ mysqli_ or PDO

Answer (score 0):

```
$date= new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
while(true)
{   
    if($date->format("w") != 1 )// 0 for sunday, 1 for monday, etc
    {
         //do things
         $date->modify("-1 day");
    }else{
         return;
    }
}
```

Comment: That avoids quering the DB